GEE output empty for S2_SR_HARMONIZED collection (but same code works for non-harmonised S2 collection)
The issue
I am trying to extract time series from polygons in Google EarthEngine using the Python API. When I run my temporal and spatial filters, the collection has more than 1000 images. However, after I map the time series extraction and flatten the output, its length is zero. This is because each extraction of values is an empty feature collection.

Minimum reproducable example
Here is a MWE to reproduce the issue. Of course, you should change authenthication (project).
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
# Imports
import os
import sys
import time
from datetime import datetime as dt
from tqdm import tqdm
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd

import requests

import ee
import geojson

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
# Settings
dir_main = os.path.dirname(os.getcwd())
dir_out = "D:/tmp"
MAXCONCURRENT = 3000
MAXREQUESTSPSEC = 100

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
# Authenticate
ee.Authenticate()

# Initialize the library.
ee.Initialize(project = "ee-manuelpopp")

s2 = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED")

start_date, end_date = "2015-06-01", "2024-08-01"

polygon_json = {'type': 'Polygon', 'coordinates': (((11.477149599999995, 46.334470100000004), (11.4769835, 46.3344901), (11.4769244, 46.3344972), (11.476769000000003, 46.33451590000001), (11.476351200000003, 46.3345506), (11.47612, 46.33454640000001), (11.4761171, 46.334547400000005), (11.4760866, 46.334570899999996), (11.4759818, 46.33459699999999), (11.4758736, 46.3345569), (11.475883299999996, 46.334552699999996), (11.475660199999998, 46.3345665), (11.4756244, 46.334566851536266), (11.4756244, 46.335691811115126), (11.476469842119506, 46.335691811115126), (11.476414, 46.33566160000001), (11.476459500000002, 46.3356034), (11.476586199999998, 46.335593499999995), (11.4767342, 46.3355975), (11.4768112, 46.3355506), (11.476788700000004, 46.3355106), (11.476851199999999, 46.3354473), (11.477000700000003, 46.3354083), (11.477104899999997, 46.335432299999994), (11.4771652, 46.335488000000005), (11.4771778, 46.335499700000014), (11.476938675943686, 46.335691811115126), (11.4774582, 46.335691811115126), (11.4774582, 46.33445624127443), (11.477151400000002, 46.3344699), (11.477149599999995, 46.334470100000004)), ((11.4758755, 46.335385099999996), (11.4760321, 46.3353507), (11.476118399999997, 46.335358400000004), (11.476134600000004, 46.3354128), (11.476123, 46.3354607), (11.476104500000002, 46.335508700000005), (11.476028799999998, 46.3355842), (11.4759373, 46.335612399999995), (11.4758525, 46.3356396), (11.4757915, 46.3355822), (11.4756933, 46.3355391), (11.4756769, 46.335479899999996), (11.4757678, 46.335437399999996), (11.4758755, 46.335385099999996)))}
aoi = ee.Geometry.Polygon(polygon_json["coordinates"])

collection = s2.filterBounds(aoi).filterDate(start_date, end_date)

if collection.size().getInfo() == 0:
    print(f"No images found for AOI {idx} after filtering.")
    # This is okay. there are 1001 images.

def extract_time_series(image):
    image_crs = image.select("B4").projection()
    pixel_values = image.sampleRegions(
        collection = ee.FeatureCollection(aoi),
        scale = 10,
        projection = image_crs,
        tileScale = 1,
        geometries = True
        )
    
    return pixel_values.map(
        lambda feature: feature.set("date", image.date().format())
        )

time_series = collection.map(extract_time_series).flatten()

if time_series.size().getInfo() > 0:
    print("We got some features!")
else:
    print(f"No values for polygon.")
    # This is not okay. We have no features anymore, here.


Additional information
The interesting thing is, the script worked when I used another Sentinel 2 collection. If I change the collection to:
s2 = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2")

or
s2 = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR")

I get plenty of features. However, I need the harmonised data, so I have to use S2_SR_HARMONIZED.
Yes, I would expect fewer images with the newer collection. However, since I use the exact same AOI to subset the collection and to extract values, I would not expect to get zero output. Besides, I translated the code to run in the browser version of GEE and I could display the area of interest along with images from the time series to confirm that 1. the area of interest is not empty or malformed, 2. the area of interest overlaps with images of the collection, and 3. the images have valid values within the area of interest.
I am using (should not matter, though):

Python version 3.12.5
ee version 0.1.417

Here is the full code I used:
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
# Imports
import os
import sys
import time
from datetime import datetime as dt
from tqdm import tqdm
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd

import requests

import ee
import geojson

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
# Settings
dir_main = os.path.dirname(os.getcwd())
dir_out = "D:/tmp"
MAXCONCURRENT = 3000
MAXREQUESTSPSEC = 100

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
# Authenticate
ee.Authenticate()

# Initialize the library.
ee.Initialize(project = "ee-manuelpopp")

# Areas of interest
gdf = gpd.read_file(
    os.path.join(
        dir_main, "dat/db/Disturbances_coverage.gpkg"
    ), layer = "Union"
    ).explode(index_parts = False).reset_index(drop = True)

s2 = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED")

start_date, end_date = "2015-06-01", "2024-08-01"
t_start = dt.now()
REMAINING_PARALLEL = 0

for idx, row in tqdm(
        gdf.iterrows(), total = gdf.shape[0], desc = "Processing AOIs"
        ):
    if (idx >= (dt.now() - t_start).seconds * MAXREQUESTSPSEC):
        time.sleep(1)
    
    polygon = row.geometry
    polygon_json = polygon.__geo_interface__
    aoi = ee.Geometry.Polygon(polygon_json["coordinates"])
    
    collection = s2.filterBounds(aoi).filterDate(start_date, end_date)
    
    if collection.size().getInfo() == 0:
        print(f"No images found for AOI {idx} after filtering.")
        continue
    
    def extract_time_series(image):
        image_crs = image.select("B4").projection()
        aoi_utm = aoi.transform(image_crs, maxError = 1)
        pixel_values = image.sampleRegions(
            collection = ee.FeatureCollection(aoi_utm),
            scale = 10,
            projection = image_crs,
            tileScale = 1,
            geometries = True
            )
        
        return pixel_values.map(
            lambda feature: feature.set("date", image.date().format())
            )
    
    time_series = collection.map(extract_time_series).flatten()
    
    if time_series.size().getInfo() > 0:
        export_task = ee.batch.Export.table.toDrive(
            folder = "tmp",
            collection = ee.FeatureCollection(time_series),
            description = f"TS{str(idx).zfill(6)}"
            )
    else:
        print(f"No values for polygon {idx}. Skipping...")
        continue
    
    while REMAINING_PARALLEL < 1:
        tasks = ee.batch.Task.list()
        ready_tasks = [
            task for task in tasks if task.state == "READY"
            ]
        
        running_tasks = [
            task for task in tasks if task.state == "RUNNING"
            ]
        
        completed_tasks = [
            task for task in tasks if task.state == "COMPLETED"
            ]

        REMAINING_PARALLEL = MAXCONCURRENT - len(
            running_tasks
            ) - len(ready_tasks)
        
        if REMAINING_PARALLEL < 1:
            print_flush(
                f"Running jobs: {len(running_tasks)}\n" +
                f"Pending tasks: {len(ready_tasks)}\n"
                )
            time.sleep(60)
    
    if not os.path.isfile(os.path.join(dir_out, f"TS{str(idx).zfill(6)}.csv")):
        export_task.start()
        REMAINING_PARALLEL -= 1


The collection contains masked bands resulting in null-valued properties, which are dropped when returning the output of sampleRegions. See the answer of this question.
To resolve this, select the relevant bands you need and make sure they are not masked. See here a working JavaScript example, and the lines to add in your script below
ListOfBandsYouNeed = ['B2','B3','B4'] #  check there is no masked bands
collection = collection.select(ListOfBandsYouNeed)


Thanks, this solved the problem. This behaviour is not really intuitive...
